# Hypodermic - OnActivating

Tags: c++, dependency-injection, hypodermic

I've been recently trying to use https://github.com/ybainier/Hypodermic for dependency injection on C++. Yet, I am unable to find if it supports the OnActivating event from AutoFac:

```
builder.RegisterInstance(instance).OnActivating(MyLambdaHere)
```

Is there any way on Hypodermic to mimic this functionality?

Answer (score 9):

This feature comes with the *new release* (0.1.2). You can use it like so:

```
builder.registerInstance(instance)->onActivating(
    [](IActivatingData< MyStaticInstanceType >& data) -> void
    {
        // Your "Activating" code here
    }
);
```

Besides, `IRegistrationBuilder` exposes `onPreparing()` and `onActivated()` as well. I hope that helps.